# input accept not working for docx files in chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, file-upload

I need to restrict file upload to "docx" files in chrome. I know that accept attribute of the input tag can do this in chrome. I actually did restrict chrome upload to  regular doc files before,   so now I added mime type for docx and its not working. here is my test form

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=cp1251">
<title>test</title>
</head>
<body style='background-color: white'>
<FORM action=" ">
<input type="file" accept="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Am I missing something? Typo somewhere? my chrome version is 29.0.1547.66 m

Comment: For uploads, your `<form>` needs `enctype="multipart/form-data"`.

Comment: i ve added it  <FORM action=""  enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">   still no luck

Comment: What *exactly* is your issue?  What's not working?  When I run this code in Chrome 30.0.1599.37 beta-m, I see a file browser that only displays docx files.

Comment: @Azat: It is possible that your local machine doesn't have the proper MIME-type to file-extension association.  I'd suggest a method to check, but don't know what platform you're running this under.

Comment: I am working on windows 7 x64 . By not working i mean  that file browser  filter shows "all files" and not the "custom files"  that would indicate that filter is working